# How to transfer a boolean from app delegate to a viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, appdelegate

I'm currently trying to transfer a variable from app delegate to a ViewController. Most of the guides I find are in objective-c and I don't have the skill to convert that code into swift. Could someone help me find a way to do this.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        var isIpad: Bool!
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            isIpad = true
            print("iPad")

        }else{
            print("not iPad")
            isIpad = false
        }

    }
```

Comment: post the code ..

Comment: there is the only code i have i didnt know where to start

Comment: 1. Why are you checking for iPad vs. iPhone? Make your decisions based on view size, not device type. 2. Why do this in `applicationDidBecomeActive`? It won't change each time the app becomes active. 3. Why have a variable for this at all and why in the app delegate? Just do the check where you need it (but see point #1).

Comment: Thank you but I'm not looking for an alternative. I'm fine with what I'm trying to do because it gets the job done. My app will go to different view controllers depending on the device type.

Comment: "I'm fine with what I'm trying to do because it gets the job done." You haven't made it clear what you are trying to get done. You say you want to pass a bool from your app delegate to a ViewController. What bool? `isIpad`? What view controller? Are you saying that each time your app becomes active you want to tell it "You're still running on an iPad!" It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is run a view controller depending on the device,

Comment: Btw, there are Objective-C-to-Swift converters online, like https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home

Comment: Side note, there's no reason to make `isIpad` either an implicitly unwrapped optional or a `var` in your current code, since it's always going to be assigned exactly once.

Comment: you better to add all what you need in the post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although I would suggest to take a look to @rmaddy's first comment, you could declare a *stored property* anywhere in the module (it doesn't has to be declared in the app delegate):

```
let isIpad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
```

It means that there is no need to pass a value from the app delegate to the view controller. Thus in the view controller -for example-:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if isIpad {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't encourage global vars , also computed is meant for changing content , Will the device change someWhere inside the app ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan why? is it because there is no need to get computed each time it gets called?